# Google BigQuery dataset

Tags: odbc, google-bigquery, simba

I have installed simba Google BigQuery ODBC driver (V2.0) and would like to connect publicdata (Sample dataset) to third party application through ODBC driver. I tried to create DSN. In catalog(project) drop down box, Publicdata project does not displayed. Anybody know the reason?

Is it needed to activate billing account to use public dataset?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm trying to do the same. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like I hit the same issue myself:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63817037/problem-installing-the-magnitude-simba-windows-10-bigquery-odbc-drivers

If you have a solution, let us know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is not necessary have a Billing account, if you try the CData trial version, you can access to each public database. Its problem is that is very expensive, so Simba would be a great solution. Instead, I´ve continued with the same question on my mind.